# What is aborting my jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

I am executing an AJAX call via $.get, and it's aborting after a few seconds (around 5). In the error function, if I call `getAllResponseHeaders()` on the first argument (`xhr`), the response is an empty string (`""`), which seems to indicate that the abortion is coming from client side, not server side. This is driving me crazy because there's no code anywhere that would be manually aborting this request.

Also worth noting that simply hitting the URL in my browser window completes the request immediately with no issue.

How can I determine the code that is causing the AJAX request to abort?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the domain you're making the request to the same as the one your site is hosted on? It sounds like you're being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Good question, but yes, same domain.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of the console to see what the status code of the request comes back as, and what content it has?

Comment: Yes. The XHR tab of Firebug is unhelpful because it doesn't have a Response tab at all on the expanded line of the aborted request. And that's unusual (I think). But if I set a breakpoint in the error function I can inspect the xhr response, and the status code is 0. Not sure what I'd look for to see the content you mentioned, although my question states that I checked the `getAllResponseHeaders()` function and that returned an empty string.

Comment: Try the network console in Chrome - it's better than Firebug. It would help to see some of your code though. Specifically around the request itself and any other events which are occurring at the same time.

Comment: The request completes fine in Chrome. So that's a clue...